# Is there a Gradian sinus function in Excel?

Tags: excel

I'd like to use Gradian sinus instead of the regular radian sinus in Excel, Is there a built in function ?

Couldn't find information about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you'd have to convert (e.g. if the value in gradians was in A2)

```
=SIN(A2*PI()/200)
```